# generates a key in AES padding CBC

Tags: c#, class, key, aes

I'm new to C #
and I generates a key

`myRijndaelManaged.GenerateIV ();
myRijndaelManaged.GenerateKey ();`

in Class

```
public string EncryptText(string plainText)
    {
        using (myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        {

            RijndaelManaged myRijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
            myRijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            myRijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            myRijndaelManaged.GenerateIV();
            myRijndaelManaged.GenerateKey();      
            string newKey = ByteArrayToHexString(myRijndaelManaged.Key);
            string newinitVector = ByteArrayToHexString(myRijndaelManaged.IV);
            byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(plainText, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);
            string encString = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
            return encString;
        }
    }
```

How to give the same keys in class

```
public string DecryptText(string encryptedString)  
    {  
        using (myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())  
        {  
            myRijndael.Key =newKey;
            myRijndael.IV = newinitVector;  
            myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;  
            myRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;  
            Byte[] ourEnc = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString);  
            string ourDec = DecryptStringFromBytes(ourEnc, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);  
            return ourDec;  
        }  
    }
```

When I give another key I have a problem with
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: „Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.”

Answer (score 0):

Although I am no expert at encryption but it still makes sense to me. I mean, you should pass the iv and key generated to the function that decrypts.
For example:

```
public string DecryptText(string encryptedString, string Iv, string Key)  
    {  
        using (myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())  
        {  
            myRijndael.Key = Key;
            myRijndael.IV = Iv;  
            myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;  
            myRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;  
            Byte[] ourEnc = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString);  
            string ourDec = DecryptStringFromBytes(ourEnc, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);  
            return ourDec;  
        }  
    }
```

Well,  I am not sure what the data types of the Iv and Key are, change them to suit  yourself.